# Is it possible to write a script to write the google sheet address to a specific cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm adding hyperlinks to my google sheet that are copied throughout the worksheet.  I have a table of contents with sheet names in A2:A and would like to write a google app script to write the specific sheet URL to the corresponding cell in B2:B.  The hyperlinks throughout my workbook reference the TOC based on a vlookup and function correctly as long as the correct URL is held in B2:B.

I use the workbook as a template that is copied as new projects are developed.  The links should change every time the workbook is copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A list of sheet names and sheet URLs

This will create your list:

```
function getSheetNamesAndUrls() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  var vA=[['SheetName','SheetURL']];//if you don't want headers remove this
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    vA.push([shts[i].getName(),'docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d' + ss.getId() + '/edit#gid=' + shts[i].getSheetId()]);
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);//if you already have headers then make this 2,1,vA.length...
}
```

- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

Comment: Thank you this was the answer I needed.  I made the following edits                              
  var ssn=ss.getId();


vA.push([shts[i].getName(),'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + ssn + '/edit#gid=' + shts[i].getSheetId()]);
  }

Comment: @RosPosey Thanks. I updated the answer with your edits in case anyone else wants the same thing.